# Extending Wagtail Modeladmin CreateView I get a NoReverseMatch and if I comment the code the routing problem persists

Tags: python, django, wagtail, modeladmin

On wagtail modeladmin for a given model, I need to modify the *Create_Button* so that it shows a create view with a **subset of model fields** and adding an **API call to an external service**.

Overriding the Edit Button I could do this seamlessly, just binding the property

```
#wagtail_hooks.py
class MyModelAdmin(Modeladmin):
    model = MyModel
    ...
    edit_view_class = MyModelEditView
    ...
```

and on the MyModelEditView(EditView) just added my extended logic on the form_valid method.

Following the same pattern, I created a **MyModelCreateView(CreateView)**,
added the property to MyModelAdmin as:
create_view_class=MyModelCreateView

which is defined like:

```
#wagtail_hooks.py
class MyModelCreateView(CreateView):

    """
     we only want user to define 2 fields of the model, then call an API REST 
    that returns the other fields, then save object to backend db
    """

    panels = [                                                                                      
            FieldPanel('field1'),                                                                 
            FieldPanel('field2')                                                                
            ]                                                                                       
                                                                                                    
    def get_edit_handler(self):                                                                     
        panels = self.panels                                                                        
        edit_handler = ObjectList(panels).bind_to(model=MyModel, request=self.request)               
        return edit_handler
                                                                          
    def create_mymodel(self, form):                                                              
        data = form.cleaned_data                                                                    
        for field in data:
            data[field] = cleanup(field)                                                                        
                                                           
        res = requests.post(...)
        if res.status_code == 200:                                                                  
            logger.info("created mymodel")
            ...                                            
        else:                                                                                       
            logger.error(f"something went wrong: {res.status_code}\n{res.content}")
            ...

                 
        return True                                                                                 
                                                                                                    
    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):                                                    
        
        res = self.create_mymodel(form)                                                         
        try:                                                                                       
            self.form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)                                                 
        except Exception:                                                                          
            print(Exception)                                                                       
        form_valid_return = super().form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)                               
        return form_valid_return
```

Once define this, with many doubts on which modeladmin classmethods should I override to achieve our needs: get_context_data, dispatch, form_valid, ...
is just a matter of python manage.py runserver, navigate to the admin/mymodel path, and crash:

```
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 676, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'mymodel_modeladmin_edit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/mymodel/edit/(?P<instance_pk>[-\\w]+)/$']
[15/Jul/2020 15:08:08] "GET /admin/mymodel/ HTTP/1.1" 500 798083
```

So you think, Ok, I did something wrong, comment last code, put a ipdb trace ... and the problem persists with the NoReverseMatch, there's no way to get rid of this.

Clean browser cache, switch to another browser, re-run runserver, re-create database, nothing makes this issue go back to stable.

Eventually you switch git branch, re-run git clone, re-install virtualenv, drop backend db, and then you have a fresh local implementation of your project, until I try to mess again with this problem.

So my question is, what the hell is going on? where is this cached routing thing ? I've worked with django for many years and never faced such behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

did you try looking for the urls in your application:
try this command

```
./manage.py show_urls | grep /create/
```

do you see any instance pk with creating views?

Comment: hi @ladhari, I don't have this management command. The point Is that I never defined an URL for this since I'm overriding a wagtail modeladmin button, I'm not changing wagtail URLs or anything internal, just trying to add functionality to the Create button.

Comment: @serpiko sorry for not being useful with this problem, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: yes I managed to workaround it after going through all the doc and parent classes for modeladmin editview and createview. Never found out why the routes crashed by that way, but these two classes behave way differently, they lack documentation and parent classes are too spaguettised to my taste.

Comment: What worked for me was overwriting these methods:

for **CreateView**: 
- __get_form_kwargs__ to add an API call that populates the form fields before render.
- __dispatch__: to add another API call that updates data for previous creation request and modify the object and save to database.
for **EditView**:
- __dispatch__: get context_data()["instance"] and make transformations to fields content before model.object.save() 
- __form_valid__: validate form fields and sync with external API.

thanks for your help ;)

Comment: glad to know that you succeeded to resolve it! sorry that I was not so helpful